# Non-gravitational example of unstable equilibria

Tags: soft-question, dynamical-systems, education, stability-theory

A bit of a soft question: When talking to beginning students in dynamics, I often use some intuitive examples to illustrate the idea of stable vs unstable equilibria. The classics are a pendulum hanging downwards vs balancing upwards, or a rock sitting in a valley vs a rock sitting on top of a hill. However recently a student asked me for an example that didn't involve the gravitational force, and I wasn't able to come up with a compelling intuitive example off the top of my head. Does anybody have any examples they could recommend? I think for teaching purposes, an example would be especially useful if it contained both a stable and an unstable equilibrium point, like in the pendulum example, but this isn't strictly necessary.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: The gravitational force is the one we are most familiar on a daily basis, so it seems to me that even the ones that I can think of (like eletrical systems) are not that intuitive. However something with springs might do the trick, like, a spring's equilibrium position is a point of stable equilibrium, but I don't know if you can find some simple system with elastic behaviour that has a point of unstable equilibrium (without gravitational force)

Comment: We really need some example from biology or economy here :)

Comment: @LourencoEntrudo, I was also thinking about springs as a source for intuitive examples, but finding an arrangement where a springs system has unstable equilibria seemed pretty contrived.

Comment: @StinkingBishop, yes, those are exactly the types of examples I'm interested in :)

Comment: The logisitc ode $x'=ax-bx^2$ is cosidered as a simple population model (including negative effects of overpopulation). The empty environment $x=0$ is an unstable equilibrium. Small positive populations always grow towards the stable equilibrium $a/b$.

Comment: The widely misused zombie apocalypse model (also called SIR model) has an unstable equilibrium with zero infected.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for all of the responses - the examples from population biology (logistic model, SIR model) are perfect for my purposes.